# django-compressor not working on less files in production

Tags: django, less, django-compressor

I'm not sure what caused this, it was working earlier. The problem is that I'm not getting any useful debug information in my logs, so I don't know where the failure is occurring.

```
{% compress css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.less" />
{% block extrastyle %}  
{% endblock %}
{% endcompress %}
```

It's not processing the less file. The output is currently:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" href="/static/css/style.less" />
```

It is, however, minifying the javascript I have at the end of the `<body>` tag, so compress is enabled, but it's just not processing the less block.

My production settings have `DEBUG=False`. I got into a shell using `manage.py shell --settings=settings.production`, and checked my django settings:

```
from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.COMPRESS_ENABLED
True
>>> settings.COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS
(('text/less', 'lessc {infile} {outfile}'),)
```

lessc seems to work fine from commandline:

```
$ lessc test.css /tmp/out.css
```

How can I find out what's causing this to happen?

Comment: Did my solution help or are you still having trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with my less path. The lessc binary that was being run was a different version than the one that needed to be run.

Answer (score 2):

Try `./manage.py compress --force` and that will force compress your assets and show which line, if any, is tripping it up.  My project had small `@import` reference problems and that broke it in production.